# Error with RawStringFormats in clang-format in CLion

Tags: c++, clion, clang-format

I'm trying to use a `clang-format` file in CLion but CLion gives me the error:
`Error reading [path to clang-format]: Invalid Argument`

The error has to do with the `RawStringFormats` in my `.clang-format` file. When I remove the `RawStringFormats` section, CLion gives me no errors.

My `.clang-format` file is auto-generated by a script using Google's standards.

I need to find out the cause of the problem so I can modify the script to prevent this issue.

```
RawStringFormats: 
  - Delimiter:       pb
    Language:        TextProto
    BasedOnStyle:    google
```

Comment: you probably generated the format file with an old version of clang-format. Newer versions have slightly different `RawStringFormats` paremeters. Therefore, make sure both versions (your generating and the editors one) are matching

Comment: Maybe there is a quicker way but I used `echo "" | clang-format --dry-run` to validate the file

Answer (score 6):

`Delimiters` is an array parameter, so

```
RawStringFormats:
  - Language: TextProto
    BasedOnStyle: Google
    Delimiters: [pb]
```

`CLion` has a schema validator, and `pb` in your example is highlighted by yellow in editor. The tooltip shows the message:

`Schema validation: incompatible types`
`Required: array. Actual: String`

[image: CLion validator message]

Comment: I just want to add that it's not only `pb` -> `[pb]` but also the key is pluralized `Delimiter` -> `Delimiters`.